# best strategy to query items from dynamodb

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table with products that have ID, name and few other attributes that I want to use to filter (eg. color, type, manufacturer).

I want to set ID as primary key, name as sort key, and thinking how to handle others for query like
api/products?color=X&type=Y&manufacturer=Z

Will it be good solution to create global secondary index for each attribute (color, type, manifacturer)?
So with such request I would do 3 queries that would return 3 lists of records with ID that I would use to query base on primary key.

Comment: You may want to consider the possibility that DynamoDB isn't the right choice for this use case.

Comment: Creating 3 or more GSI won't help because you can only use one index for scan and others will be applied as the filters. Depending on the number of records, it could potentially impact the performance. Or you can create a new 'compound' attribute that stores all three values.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to separate two different things which are similar: querying, and searching. If you want your API to provide the capability to query, then DynamoDB with a couple of GSIs should cover most all your requirements.

If you want your API to just search through a bunch of data, then IMO you're moving away from standard databases and into the realm of search engines, so it may be worth looking at AWS CloudSearch or Elasticsearch, or something like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) which are technologies specifically designed for search.

For DynamoDB design, I recommend this video on advanced design patterns: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k

In about 1-2 hours you will learn a whole lot about using DynamoDB, including best practices about how to model relational access patterns on it. About 50 minutes in you can see a large example table from which you can glean the design decisions to achieve a certain set of access patterns.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I am surprised that nobody else upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Michael - sqlbot said, first things first, you should consider the possibility that DynamoDB is not the right choice.

To help you with it I strongly recommend you to [read the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) (if you don't already). DynamoDB is a very powerful NoSQL database system, but it can be very tricky as well.

With such simple case you should be able to solve it without GSIs. Keep in mind that using GSIs may implicate consuming extra WCUs every time you add/update/delete an item in the base table. And keep in mind that GSIs are eventually consistent which may or may not be a problem, depending on you case.

You may want to consider other NoSQL solutions like Cassandra, MongoDB, CouchDB, etc, as well.